# Рекурсивная функция в C++. Нахождение наибольшего элемента в массиве

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть такая задача: с помощью рекурсивной функции найти наибольший элемент в массиве, путём деления массива на две половины на каждой волне.

Никак не могу придумать алгоритм для решения этой задачи. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализовал один из вариантов рекурсивного максимума делением массива пополам.

Я не проверяю что массив не пустой, по условию считаю что он всегда не пустой.

Также элементарно убрать использование хедеров `<vector>` и `<algorithm>`, если по условию это не разрешено использовать.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/KcEv9P5h6)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int Max(int const * a, int size) {
    if (size <= 1)
        return a[0];
    return std::max(
        Max(&a[0], size / 2),
        Max(&a[size / 2], size - size / 2)
    );
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {8, 2, 20, 3, 5, 7, 1};
    std::cout << Max(a.data(), a.size()) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
20
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)